Is a sofic shift a closed set?
Let $X$ be a sofic shift (on the alphabet $\Sigma$). Define the usual metric
$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
        2^{-k} & \text{if $x\neq y$ and $k$ is maximal such that $x_{[-k,k]} = y_{[-k,k]}$}, \\ 
        0 & \text{if $x=y$}.
    \end{cases}$$
Is $X$ closed in the induced metric topology?

$\textbf{Definition 3.1.3.}$ A subset $X$ of a full shift is a $\textsf{sofic shift}$ if $X = \mathsf{X}_{\mathcal{G}}$ for some labeled graph $\mathcal{G}$. A $\textsf{presentation}$ of a sofic shift $X$ is a labeled graph $\mathcal{G}$ for which $\mathsf{X}_{\mathcal{G}} = X$. The shift map on $\mathsf{X}_{\mathcal{G}}$ is denoted $\sigma_{\mathcal{G}}$.


Yes, but the proof will depend on the particular definition of sofic shift you're using.

I am using the definition from Lind and Marcus 2021. I will edit the question to include the definition.

Let $[u.v] = \{x \in \mathcal{A}^\mathbb{Z} \mid x_{[-k,k]}=uv\}$, where $|u|=k,\,|v|=k+1$ for some $k \geq 0$. These are generally called 'central cylinder sets' and they're both closed and open (this is proved in page 179, Lind-Marcus 2021).
Any finite union of central cylinder sets is therefore also open and closed - in particular, $C_k$, the union of all length $2k+1$ central cylinder sets that correspond to valid paths in $\mathcal{G}$ is closed. From the definition, $X_{\mathcal{G}} = \bigcap_{k \geq 0}C_k$. Therefore, $X_\mathcal{G}$ is an infinite intersection of closed sets, which is closed.

Thank you for your answer. I do have a question about the definition of central cylinder sets: $[-k,k]$ has $2k+1$ indices, however $uv$ only has $2k$. Could you please provide some clarification on this definition?
This is irrelevant to your argument which still holds, but I would like to learn about cylinders anyways.

Just a typo, $|v|=k+1$.
